# How can I get the Google Pixel 3 emulator in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-pixel

I'm currently running the latest version of Android Studio, v3.2.1. The virtual devices available only go up to the Pixel 2 (and the XL version). These do not suffice since I mainly need to test on the new Google Pixel 3 XL, due to its notch.

[image]

Is it possible to get the new Pixel 3 (and XL version) loaded into Android Studio's emulators for testing?

Comment: just add custom emulator with pixel 3 screen size and density, RAM amount, etc.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko will that simulate the notch? Cuz that's the #1 reason I can think how a Pixel 3XL emulator would be useful.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko - That will not simulate the notch on the Pixel 3 XL though.

Comment: Notch? You mean the skin of pixel 3?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko - Note the notch at the top of the device in this image - https://boygeniusreport.files.wordpress.com/2018/08/pixel-3-xl-leak-2.jpg

Comment: ah, ok, got it. It is likely not supported by Android emulator yet so far

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To add a notch in the emulator, choose any device with Android Pie system image (9.0). Build it, then go to Settings > System > expand 'Advanced' > Developer options > 'Drawing' section > 'Simulate a display with a cutout' on the emulator.

You can use it until they add the official skin

[image]

*NOTE: The 'Developer' option is not shown by default on Android phones. Please see the [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options) to learn out how to enable it.

Comment: This seems to be the only way to emulate the notch for the time being. Thank you.

Comment: it disappearing once app start? why?

Comment: In Google Pixel3 XL, "Simulate a display with a cutout" name is changed to "Display Cutout"

Answer (score 14):

To save other's some searching, here's the configuration necessary for a custom Pixel 3 XL hardware profile:

> **Device Type:** Phone/Tablet
>   **Screen Size:** 6.3 inch
>   **Resolution:** 1440x2960 px
>   **RAM:** 8192 MB
>   **Has Hardware Buttons:** false
>   **Has Hardware Keyboard:** false
>   **Navigation Style:** none
>   **Supported Device States:** Portrait=true, Landscape=true
>   **Cameras:** Back-facing=true, Front-facing=true
>   **Sensors:** Accelerometer=true, Gyroscope=true, GPS=true, Proximity=true
>   **Default Skin:** No Skin

[image]

Then you can enable the notch developer option [mentioned by Mohamed Saber](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53235382/1169961) and you should have a pretty accurate representation of a Pixel 3 XL.

Answer (score 14):

Official AVDs for Pixel 3 and Pixel 3 XL are available since Android Studio 3.4