# Custom hardware profile with Google Play Store

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to create a custom virtual device in Android Studio to emulate my Pixel 3 phone and I am having difficulty getting it to work, so I wanted to see if the steps I am using are correct or there is something better I should be doing.

I followed the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53148978/how-can-i-get-the-google-pixel-3-emulator-in-android-studio) and cloned the Pixel 2 profile, then manually edited it to specify the Pixel 3 dimensions, resolution, etc. I am using Android Studio 3.3.1 with the latest updates.

I am hitting two problems with that:
 1) When I try to import that profile, it loses the "Play Store" setting and the newly started image doesn't have Google Play Services checked [(see screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQhCA.png)
 2) When I start that image it gets stuck at the "Preparing for setup phase" of what I think is the Android SDK [(see screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0V0NS.png)

My questions are - is what I am doing supported (or supposed to work at all) and if not, is there a better way to get a custom-sized device image with Google Play services on it?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 23):

open file in: `USER_HOME/.android/avd/[YOUR_AVD].avd/config.ini`

and edit / add this:

```
PlayStore.enabled=true
image.sysdir.1=system-images\android-29\google_apis_playstore\x86\
tag.display=Google Play
tag.id=google_apis_playstore
hw.device.manufacturer=Google
hw.device.name=Nexus 5
```

Maybe not all required, but `PlayStore.enabled` and `image.sysdir.1` is required. `image.sysdir.1` depends on your installed Android AVD version...

Comment: This worked great for me. Only needed to change 'PlayStore.enabled' and 'image.sysdir.1' as mtrakal suggested. Thanks.

Comment: This worked for me :-) And it finally it downloaded the image which have Google Play store. So bottom line is not all image have Google play store by default.

Comment: This worked great, just want to add that you will have to start avd from android studio so that it downloads updated playstore images, running avd directly will probably throw some error.

Comment: @ShashiShekhar of course it depends on what images you have currently downloaded otherwise it need to download image (which is not possible by command line start).  You can replace `android-29` with another version of your preferred API level which you have downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working with Android 10.0 image. Tested with a modified Nexus 5 profile.

Answer (score 0):

Juste in case: After 4 years... i hade exactly the same problem. and after many tests, it was because the generated devices.xml was containing:

```
<d:device>
<d:name>Zerbra_001_API_25</d:name>
<d:manufacturer>User</d:manufacturer>
<d:meta/>
<d:hardware>
  <d:screen>
    <d:screen-size>normal</d:screen-size>
    <d:diagonal-length>4.30</d:diagonal-length>
    <d:pixel-density>220dpi</d:pixel-density>
```

i replace 220dpi by hdpi:

```
<d:device>
<d:name>Zerbra_001_API_25</d:name>
<d:manufacturer>User</d:manufacturer>
<d:meta/>
<d:hardware>
  <d:screen>
    <d:screen-size>normal</d:screen-size>
    <d:diagonal-length>4.30</d:diagonal-length>
    <d:pixel-density>hdpi</d:pixel-density>
```

And **Eurêka!!!** The new created virtual device is working perfectly!

I hope it helps someone.

```
      IDE:
            Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 2
            Build #AI-231.9392.1.2311.11330709, built on January 19, 2024
            Runtime version: 17.0.7+0-b2043.56-10550314 amd64
            VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
            Windows 11.0
            GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
            Memory: 2048M
            Cores: 16
            Registry:
                external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
                debugger.watches.in.variables=false
                debugger.new.tool.window.layout=true
                ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false
                ide.experimental.ui=true
            
            Non-Bundled Plugins:
                Dart (231.9411)
                com.localizely.flutter-intl (1.18.4-2022.2)
                io.flutter (78.0.1)
                de.mariushoefler.flutter_enhancement_suite (1.7.1)
            

    Windows:

            Édition Windows 11 Professionnel
            Version 23H2
            Installé le ‎25/‎05/‎2023
            Build du système d’exploitation 22631.3155
            Expérience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22684.1000.0



    adb --version
            Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
            Version 35.0.0-11411520
```